# Transform an array of objects by removing object properties not contained in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, transform

A long title, so I´ll explain the problem by example. I have an array of objects:

```
const myObjects = [
   {
      id: 1,
      name: "a",
      stuff: "x"
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      name: "b",
      stuff: "y"
   },
];
```

Then I have another array of objects like this:

```
const myTemplate=[
   {
      desiredProperty: "name",
      someOtherProperty: "..."
   },
   {
      desiredProperty: "stuff",
      someOtherProperty: "..."
   },
];
```

Now I want to transform myObjects array to new one, so that the individual objects contain only the properties listed in desiredProperty of each object in myTemplate.
The result should look like this:

```
myResult = [
   {
      name: "a",
      stuff: "x"
   },
   {
      name: "b",
      stuff: "y"
   }
]
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Your template doesn't make sense to me. Why is it an array of objects? Why not just an array of strings for the keys you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code creates a `Set` of the keys you want to keep. Then, we `map` over your `myObjects` array and only keep the object keys that are in the `toKeep` Set.

```js
const myObjects=[{id:1,name:"a",stuff:"x"},{id:2,name:"b",stuff:"y"}];
const myTemplate=[{desiredProperty:"name",someOtherProperty:"..."},{desiredProperty:"stuff",someOtherProperty:"..."}];

const toKeep = new Set(myTemplate.map(t => t.desiredProperty));

const newObjs = myObjects.map(o => {
  const obj = {};
  for (let key in o) {
    if (toKeep.has(key)) {
      obj[key] = o[key];
    }
  }
  return obj;
});

console.log(newObjs);
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach lets you partially apply the template to get back a reusable function to run against multiple sets of inputs:

```js
const convert = (template, keys = new Set (template .map (t => t .desiredProperty))) => (xs) =>
  xs .map (
    (x) => Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (x) .filter (([k, v]) => keys .has (k)))
  )

const myObjects = [{id: 1, name: "a", stuff: "x"}, {id: 2, name: "b", stuff: "y"}]
const myTemplate= [{desiredProperty: "name", someOtherProperty: "..."}, {desiredProperty: "stuff", someOtherProperty: "..."}]

console .log (
  convert (myTemplate) (myObjects)
)
```

But I agree with the comment that the template here is better expressed as an array of keys to keep.